# After creating a new sites List Page How can I add values to it?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have created  a new List Page but don't know how to populate it with values. As newDomainpage doesn't contain any values yet, I keep getting a NULL error while trying to set the value.

```
var domainPage = SitesApp.getPageByUrl("https://sites.google.com/a/idearebel.com/url-of-page");
var newDomainPage = newClientPage.createListPage(projectName, projectUrl, domainPageContent, [ "Used", "Title", "Notes" ]);

var domainPageItems = domainPage.getListItems();
var newDomainPageitems = newDomainPage.getListItems();

for(var i in domainPageItems) {
    newDomainPageitems[i].setValueByIndex(2, domainPageItems[i].getValueByName("Title"));
    // Logger.log(domainPageItems[i].getValueByName("Title"));
}
```

I am new to Google Scripts, therefore any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved, I was using the wrong function for the job. addListItem is the correct function to use.

```
for(var i in domainPageItems) {
    newDomainPage.addListItem([ "", domainPageItems[i].getValueByName("Title"), "", "" ]);
}
```